# Variables not getting read

Tags: java

I'm working with an existing `HttpServletRequest` for an application that simply retrieves records from various databases. I'm using Eclipse IDE.

The app currently works fine and I want to extend its functionality. However when I try to add my own variables & methods to the servlet, I'm noticing the debugger skips right over them and acts as if they are commented out.

```
boolean checkName = false, checkAddress = false, checkAge = false; //All existing variables get read just fine
boolean checkCompany = false; //My own variable that doesn't get read at all
```

I've saved, refreshed, committed to the SVN repository, but all my code is getting skipped over.

**EDIT:**
I've noticed that even if I strip away existing code, that code still gets read. It seems my .java file isn't syncing for some reason.

Any ideas of what could cause this?

Comment: Have you deployed your code to the server?

Comment: Yes, all code is run/debugged on the server

Comment: Not to harangue you, but are you sure that the code *on the server* is exactly the same as the code in your IDE? Just because you commit it to SVN doesn't mean it's on the server. Oftentimes, this is a manual step you must take.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be in sync with what is on the server. Try doing a clean deployment. Clean your deployed project and deploy again.

Comment: When I'm debugging I go over each line and my code is indeed there and getting highlighted, but nothing is set as a variable.

Comment: Is it possible that there are two different versions of your classes on the server? Or, two different apps deployed that have different versions of the same class? I've seen the debugger do some nearly incomprehensible things when the source in the IDE and the bytecode running on the server didn't match.

Comment: Remember, it's taking line number info built into your class files and using them to highlight lines of the source in your IDE, but *those things could be out of sync with one another*.

Comment: That doesn't mean your code is on the server. If you want to verify this, set a breakpoint on the line where you declare `checkCompany`. Run the use case on the server and look at the debugger. Set a watch for `checkCompany`. At this point it should be undefined. Step over to the next line. If it is still not defined, it's not on the server and you need to deploy. **We're pretty confident your code is not synced up.**

Comment: @DesertIvy I've set a breakpoint that checkCompany and ran the debug. It's never defined once I step over, so I'll try to redeploy. @ David I do have two different apps that use the same class, but they don't run at the same time. Is this still a flag?

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning and Building my project solved the issue. I was used to refreshing the entire project because the changes to my UI would update, but this is not the case for the source files. This is a very high-level answer, of course.